# HAProxy redirection on 2 ports on same server

Tags: centos, docker, haproxy

I've two docker instances (app & api) and I want to split the flows between frontend & Backend with haproxy.
I've tried the following so based on url after failing to use hdr_beg flag.

```
frontend https-in
    bind 192.168.14.30:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/cert/server.pem no-sslv3
    mode http
    option httplog
    acl app url_beg /app /assets
    use_backend app if app
    default_backend api


backend app
    mode http
    option httpchk
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
    server  app1 127.0.0.1:8095

backend api
    mode http
    option httpchk
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
    server  app2 127.0.0.1:8080
```

It is still not working as expected, do anyone have a clue ?
Haproxy version 1.5.18